# Hide Google Form responses from view in Sheets until a certain condition is met

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm interested in limiting access to Form responses in Sheets until after I've had a chance to review/approve each submission. I want the response to be viewable to those I've granted view permission at that time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. May I ask you how you found this site? I'm asking because this site is based on a question-and-answer model created in 2008 by a crowd looking for an interaction focused on solving specific technical problems, which later was extended to other topics. Contrary to how questions and answers are handled in other online forums, the discussions done through comments like this are mainly focused on clarifying a specific question or answer. Usually, a follow-up question should be posted as a new question instead of making the question in a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: There is no built-in feature to do this. Use two spreadsheets, IMPORTRANGE and QUERY functions, one to automatically get all the form responses and manually set the approval status and the other to share with the users allowed viewing the approved form responses.

---

The built-in feature that integrates Google Forms and Google Sheets sends the form's responses when each form response is submitted, and the Google Sheets **Sharing** and **Protection** settings don't allow to hide a sheet or rows while allowing others to view them.

The closer built-in feature is **Filtered Views**, but there is no way to block or force access to a specific filtered view.

Considering the above, you should decide what path you would like to take.

1. No code
2. Low code (formula)
3. Low code (script)
4. Third party (Google Forms / Sheets add-on)
5. Third party (general purpose automation tools IFTTT, Zappier, ...)
6. Code (Google Forms / Sheets API)
7. ...

There are several factors to consider when deciding on a path. Many are out of the control and influence of most people who come to ask questions here. Usually, they are looking for a free and the most easy to implement solution. In this case, take the Low code (formula) path.

For this, you will need an additional spreadsheet.

1. Add a column to mark the responses you want to show others in the spreadsheet with the sheet connected to your form. Take note of the column number (A is column 1, B is column 2, and so on).
2. Add a column header and checkboxes.
3. Grab the spreadsheet URL with the sheet connected to the form.
4. In the second spreadsheet, add the following formula to A1 of the default sheet.

   - `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("RESPONSE_SPREADSHEET_URL","A:Z"),"SELECT * WHERE Col10 = true"))`.
   - Replace `RESPONSE_SPREADSHEET_URL` with the spreadsheet URL from step 3.
   - In `Col10`, replace `10` with the column number from step 1.
   - Replace `A:Z` with the range reference encompassing all the columns used by your responses sheet. If your spreadsheet has more than one sheet, and the responses sheet is not the first, the reference should include the sheet name, i.e., `Form Responses 1!A:Z`. It's unnecessary to enclose the sheet name between apostrophes; remember that both  IMPORTRANGE's parameters should be text values.
   - You must authorize access to the spreadsheet referred to by the URL. Authorize the access; otherwise, the formula cannot retrieve the values.
   - If you haven't checked any checkbox, the formula will return #N/A.
5. Share the second spreadsheet, allowing users to VIEW. Editors might copy the formula in another sheet and modify it to see all the responses.